# Creating query for particular month of the date [CrudRepository]

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to filter date by based on months. I tried creating custom function in my CrudRepository interface But the code is not compiling.

**Models:**

```
@Entity
public class Examdates {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date examdate;
}



@Entity
public class TestChoosenDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int mid;

    @OneToOne
    private UserInfo testTaker;

    @OneToOne
    private Examdates testDate;
}
```

**CRUDReposiotry**

```
@Repository
public interface TestChoosenDetailsRepo extends CrudRepository<TestChoosenDetails,Integer> {
    List<TestChoosenDetails> findTestChoosenDetailsByTestDate_ExamdateMonth(int month);
}
```

other way i have tried but not working

```
@Repository
public interface TestChoosenDetailsRepo extends CrudRepository<TestChoosenDetails,Integer> {
    List<TestChoosenDetails> findTestChoosenDetailsByTestDate_Examdate_Month(int month);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
@Query("select td from TestChoosenDetails td join td.testDate ex where month(ex.examdate) = ?1")
List<TestChoosenDetails> getByExamMonth(int month);
```

Official [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#_supported_query_keywords) and [tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java) don't contain info about ability to build repo methods with 'Month', 'Year' etc. But who knows, maybe this is an undocumented feature... ))

In anyway I think it's better to use method with custom query in this case.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to be

```
@Repository
public interface TestChoosenDetailsRepo extends CrudRepository<TestChoosenDetails,Integer> {
    List<TestChoosenDetails> findByTestDate_Examdate_Month(int month);
}
```

Comment: So what do you get when doing like this?do you get ena exception? at runtime or compile time?

Comment: Compile time error
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.examdate] of basic type
 at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.illegalDereference(AbstractPathImpl.java:82) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:174) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]